# BillQuery for getting bills giving Unauthorized error in Intuit

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm getting "Unauthorized" error while trying to use filter in Intuit:

> Exception Details: Intuit.Ipp.Exception.InvalidTokenException: Unauthorized

The code below is used to setup the Service Context:

```
string AppToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationToken"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
String realmId = HttpContext.Current.Session["realm"].ToString();
String accessToken = HttpContext.Current.Session["accessToken"].ToString();
String accessTokenSecret = HttpContext.Current.Session["accessTokenSecret"].ToString();
String consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
String consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
IntuitServicesType intuitServiceType = (IntuitServicesType)HttpContext.Current.Session["intuitServiceType"];

OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
context1 = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, AppToken, realmId, IntuitServicesType.QBO);
```

Query for retrieving the last modified bills is as below:

```
List<Bill> CustomerBills = billQry.ExecuteQuery<Bill>(context1).ToList<Bill>();
```

Please let me know, which parameter value I'm passing incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

The following code .NET DevKit code sends a malformed request body and results in a OAuth signature error.  This is a bug in the DevKit.

```
BillQuery billQry = new BillQuery();
billQry.LastUpdatedTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20);
billQry.SpecifyOperatorOption(FilterProperty.LastUpdatedTime, FilterOperatorType.AFTER);
billQry.LastUpdatedTime = DateTime.Now; 
billQry.SpecifyOperatorOption(FilterProperty.LastUpdatedTime, FilterOperatorType.BEFORE); 
billQry.PageNumber = 1;
billQry.ResultsPerPage = 15;
billQry.SpecifySortOption(SortProperty.LastUpdatedTime, SortOrderOption.HighToLow);
List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Bill>CustomerBills =billQry.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Bill>(context).ToList();
```

The workaround is to modify the sample code below to make the request and deserialize the response into Bill objects.

[Sample Code on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LvGY3vAS)

Comment: I am going  the same, but still facing the same problem of unauthorized.

Comment: What version of the DevKit are you using?  Also, please post the request/response XML (http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0200_DevKits/0100_IPP_.NET_DevKit/0600_Logging).

Comment: Hello, I am using IPP .NET DevKit 2.0 Request XML Filter=LastUpdatedTime :AFTER: 2013-02-19T16:28:39+05:30 :AND: LastUpdatedTime :BEFORE: 2013-03-11T16:28:40+05:30 & Sort=LastUpdatedTime HighToLow&PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=15 Response XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <FaultInfo xmlns="intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd">; <Message>Unauthorized OAuth Token: signature_invalid</Message> <ErrorCode>401</ErrorCode> <Cause>SERVER</Cause> </FaultInfo>

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please post the full code for this query as well?

Comment: BillQuery billQry = new BillQuery();
billQry.LastUpdatedTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20);            billQry.SpecifyOperatorOption(FilterProperty.LastUpdatedTime, FilterOperatorType.AFTER);
billQry.LastUpdatedTime = DateTime.Now;            billQry.SpecifyOperatorOption(FilterProperty.LastUpdatedTime, FilterOperatorType.BEFORE);
billQry.PageNumber=1;
billQry.ResultsPerPage =15;
billQry.SpecifySortOption(SortProperty.LastUpdatedTime, SortOrderOption.HighToLow);List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Bill>CustomerBills =billQry.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Bill>context1).ToList<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Bill>();

Comment: This is a bug in the DevKit.  You can use the modify sample code here to make the request and deserialize the response into Bill objects.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LvGY3vAS

Comment: Hi Peter, today i am using filtering, it returns only 10 records for LastUpdatedTime and it is not the filtered record. these are the First 10 updated records without filtering. I am using the below query for retrieving the today's updated record.
var body = "PageNum={0}&ResultsPerPage={1}&Filter=LastUpdatedTime :AFTER: {2} :AND: LastUpdatedTime :BEFORE: {3} & Sort=LastUpdatedTime HighToLow"; body = String.Format(body, 1, 100, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssz"), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssz"));

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the filter in the body of the request?  The first ten records would be the default response with an empty body.  If you are, please submit a support ticket with the request and response XML and we will debug further.

Comment: I have added new support request as "Bill Filtering only returns default 10 sorted records without doing any filtering from QBO", In that i have added the bill filtering code.

Comment: Hello Peter, Any Solution for bill filtering, My code is correct or not? Please provide the solution for Filtering

Comment: The filtering question was answered on the post linked below.  The above answer fixes the unauthorized error.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470150/bill-filtering-only-returns-default-10-sorted-records-without-doing-any-filterin/15557026#15557026