# Bill Filtering only returns default 10 sorted records without doing any filtering from QBO

Tags: c#-4.0, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

Please find the below code for for filtering bills, which returns only 10 sorted records even I passed the resultperpage>10.

```
public IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Bill> FilterBills(DataServices dataServices, int startPage, int resultsPerPage, DateTime After, DateTime Before)
    {
Intuit.Ipp.Security.OAuthRequestValidator oAuthRequestValidator = ((Intuit.Ipp.Security.OAuthRequestValidator)dataServices.ServiceContext.RequestValidator);

            OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
            {
                ConsumerKey = oAuthRequestValidator.ConsumerKey,
                SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
                ConsumerSecret = oAuthRequestValidator.ConsumerSecret
            };

            OAuthSession oSession = new OAuthSession(consumerContext, "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token",
                        "https://workplace.intuit.com/Connect/Begin",
                        "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token");

            oSession.AccessToken = new TokenBase
            {
                Token = oAuthRequestValidator.AccessToken,
                ConsumerKey = oAuthRequestValidator.ConsumerKey,
                TokenSecret = oAuthRequestValidator.AccessTokenSecret
            };

            var body = "PageNum={0}&ResultsPerPage={1}&Filter=LastUpdatedTime :AFTER: {2} :AND: LastUpdatedTime :BEFORE: {3} & Sort=LastUpdatedTime HighToLow";
            body = String.Format(body, startPage, resultsPerPage, After.ToString("yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssz"), Before.ToString("yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssz"));

            IConsumerRequest conReq = oSession.Request();
            conReq = conReq.Post().WithRawContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded").WithRawContent(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body)); ;
            conReq = conReq.ForUrl(dataServices.ServiceContext.BaseUrl + "bills/v2/" + dataServices.ServiceContext.RealmId);
            conReq = conReq.SignWithToken();

            Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults searchResults = (Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults)dataServices.ServiceContext.Serializer.Deserialize<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults>(conReq.ReadBody());
            IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Bill> SearchResult = ((Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Bills)(searchResults.CdmCollections)).Bill;
            return SearchResult;
 }
```

After sending the request i m getting the respose as 10 sorted bill record without getting  any error. I am using IPPDotNetDevKit 2.1.12.0 version.

Please Look into this filtering problem.

Comment: Please provide me the solution for filtering. The above code is not working for me.

Comment: peter, Thanks for reply, i am able to get Authenticated with OAuth. I have posted my details on support. Please check with that. I am working to develop saas application and this is not live. Because of that am I getting that error?

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth parameters are being passed in the body of the request in your example above and overwriting your request body, so it is defaulting to PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=20. Also, the date is formatted incorrectly.  Here is a code sample that will work.

```
public IEnumerable<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Bill> FilterBills(DataServices dataServices, int startPage, int resultsPerPage, DateTime After, DateTime Before)
{
    StringBuilder requestXML = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder responseXML = new StringBuilder();

    var requestBody =
        "PageNum={0}&ResultsPerPage={1}&Filter=LastUpdatedTime :AFTER: {2} :AND: LastUpdatedTime :BEFORE: {3}&Sort=LastUpdatedTime HighToLow";
    requestBody = String.Format(requestBody, startPage, resultsPerPage, After.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz"),
                            Before.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz"));

    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest =
        WebRequest.Create(dataServices.ServiceContext.BaseUrl + "bills/v2/" +
                            dataServices.ServiceContext.RealmId) as HttpWebRequest;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", GetDevDefinedOAuthHeader(httpWebRequest, requestBody));
    requestXML.Append(requestBody);
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] content = encoding.GetBytes(requestXML.ToString());
    using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
    }
    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    using (Stream data = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults searchResults =
            (Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults)
            dataServices.ServiceContext.Serializer.Deserialize<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.SearchResults>(
                new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd());
        return ((Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Bills) searchResults.CdmCollections).Bill.ToList();
    }
}


private string GetDevDefinedOAuthHeader(HttpWebRequest webRequest, string requestBody)
{

    OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
    {
        ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret,
        SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true

    };

    consumerContext.UseHeaderForOAuthParameters = true;

    OAuthSession oSession = new OAuthSession(consumerContext, "https://www.example.com",
                            "https://www.example.com",
                            "https://www.example.com");


    oSession.AccessToken = new TokenBase
    {
        Token = accessToken,
        ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
        TokenSecret = accessTokenSecret
    };

    IConsumerRequest consumerRequest = oSession.Request();
    consumerRequest = ConsumerRequestExtensions.ForMethod(consumerRequest, webRequest.Method);
    consumerRequest = ConsumerRequestExtensions.ForUri(consumerRequest, webRequest.RequestUri);
    if (webRequest.Headers.Count > 0)
    {
        ConsumerRequestExtensions.AlterContext(consumerRequest, context => context.Headers = webRequest.Headers);
        if (webRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> formParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (string formParameter in requestBody.Split('&'))
            {
                formParameters.Add(formParameter.Split('=')[0], formParameter.Split('=')[1]);
            }
            consumerRequest = consumerRequest.WithFormParameters(formParameters);
        }
    }

    consumerRequest = consumerRequest.SignWithToken();
    return consumerRequest.Context.GenerateOAuthParametersForHeader();
}
```

Comment: Peter for this code I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." error.

Comment: Your OAuth tokens are not valid.  Can you please test them with the API Explorer?  http://apiexplorer.developer.intuit.com/